# How to confirm the Widget Order in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, widget, qt-creator, qt6

I've just defined the order in which I want my widgets on a Qt GUI but I can't confirm my action after hours of researches. How can I do it please ?

Here is the order I defined :

[image]

I would like the widgets to be in this order : 1 - 2 - 3

But here, there are in that order : 3 - 2 - 1

I tried to build the project to see if something different happens but it just builds exactly what I see on Qt Creator :

[image]

I read the tutorial below but there's no information about my problem : [https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.3/designer-tab-order.html#:~:text=Setting%20the%20Tab%20Order,position%20in%20the%20tab%20order](https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.3/designer-tab-order.html#:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20Tab%20Order,position%20in%20the%20tab%20order).

Btw, I don't understand why it's that complicated to do such a simple thing. It's crazy that just pressing the Enter key doesn't do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean with "widget order"? Do you mean re-arranging them visually? Or tab focus order? If you want to visually re-order your widgets: It looks like you (accidentally?) switched into "Tab Order" edit mode. The first tool button in the tool bar above the editor switches back to "Edit Widgets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed. To re-order widgets, we just have to move them manually with the mouse.